# Computing efficiently intersection of n sets

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, set-intersection

I have `n` sets identified by `setId` and each one could contain an arbitrary number of elements that is a pair `(elementId, priority)`.

My algorithm should take in input two `setId`, and give in output a set containing the first `m` elements which are in the intersection of the two input set and have the highest priority (sum of priorities).

Example:

```
n=3, m=1

Set1: { (1, 1), (12, 2) }
Set2: { (1, 4), (23, 6), (33, 22) }
Set3: { (33, 1), (1, 16 }


Input: Set2, Set3
Output: { (33, 23) }
```

My question is: assuming that I have infinite space what is the best data structures I can use in order to optimize performance?

Of course precomputing all possible intersection isn't a valid answer.

**Edit**:

Realistic numbers:

- `n`, sets number, is `~ 10^6`
- average cardinality of sets is `~ 5*10^3`.

Comment: Give us a realistic number of sets and set elements. With a toy example it's rather pointless. And what do you mean by "sum of priorities"? Doesn't make sense. You have sets of tuples.

Comment: Sort by elementId then step though both sets simultaneously and add to output set when inputs match (if you see what I mean)

Comment: @Skizz: this is my approach, but it doesn't take into account `priority`, and it is quite complex `c=|Set1|+|Set2|,   O(c)+O(c * log(c))`

Comment: What are the limits on elementId and priority?

Comment: @Paddy3118: `elementId` doesn't have an upper bound, priority could be limited even to 3 values: `{ 1, 2, 3 }`

Comment: As far as I can see, the priority is only used as an ordering key after the two sets have been merged. So either sort and obtain the top m elements after you've merged the sets or use an insertion sort as you're merging the elements. There is no shortcut, you will have to merge the all the elements of both sets together as there is no way to predict the outcome of the priority summation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take one of the sets and convert it to a [hash map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). Iterate the other set, and for each member try to look up the element in the hash map. If you find it, add the result to a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)); if the size of the heap grows to one greater than the number of elements you wish to keep, throw away the lowest item in the heap.

Comment: In this way I compute the intersection for every request. I wonder if there is some pre-computation I could do.

Comment: @marka.thore you already stated that you don't want to precompute all possible intersections. You could certainly convert *all* of your sets into hash maps ahead of time.

Comment: yes, I don't want to compute *all* intersections, but if I can pre-compute something based on priority it would be great

Comment: Seems to me throwing away the element of lowest priority is wrong. Might be we want to intersect 10 sets, and after the 8th set, element `a` has a lowest priority of 0, but would get its priority buffed up to the top during intersection with sets 9 and 10.

Comment: @G.Bach the question states that the intersection will only be between 2 sets at a time. If that's incorrect, then yes the algorithm will need to be adjusted.

Comment: Oh, I read it as "choose arbitrary number of sets, find prioritized intersection of all of them" - which now that I reread it is probably not the intended question.